# How to share same object between two Documents

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have 3 Java Classes:

```
public class PubOwner{
  private PubMenu menu;
  private StaffAccount staffAccount;
}
```

In my application both pub owner and staff account will be able to login. Pub owner has complete CRUD access to the menu, but the staff account should be able to set various menu items as inactive. How should I set the MongoDB schemas for this? I was thinking of:

- annotating StaffAccount with @DBRef, in the PubOwner class
- annotating PubMenu with @DBRef in the PubOwner class
- add PubMenu field in StaffAccount and set that as @DBRef as well
- After the pub owner creates the menu, I would also update the attached staff account with the same menu. Will these objects have the same pointer? Will an update from the PubOwner on the menu items reflect as well on the StaffAccount's menu? How should I create these classes?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using DBRef and implementing a cascade save for all dependent documents